# Sentinel 1 stripping artifact

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, sar

I am processing a S1 SLC image as follows: Read>Apply orbit file>S1 TOPS Split>Radiometric Calibration (complex)>S1 TOPS Deburst>Polarimetric Speckle filter>Terrain correction (Range Doppler)

I got a scene with thick bands, one with no data and several others with different colors. Apparently the banding effect is present in the source data or at least highlighted during the S1 TOPS Deburst process. Tried to replicate the process with the full scene, however it crashes due to insufficient RAM. Tried Thermal Noise Removal yet I have not enough RAM and SNAP does not work with subset (Strip) scenes.

I am using the data from the IW2 subswath and only 3 bursts (small area of interest)

[image: Stripping is noticeable after the deburst step]

[image: Final product after terrain correction, thick bands are noticeable, not possible to correct]